# Numbers: Get max value and the value's date

Tags: numbers, macos

I have a document where one column is a date and another is a value for the date. I'd like to be able to get the maximum value and the date when that value appeared. For example if I had

|  | A (Date) | B (Value) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-02-18 | 2 |
| 2 | 2023-02-19 | 7 |
| 3 | 2023-02-20 | 3 |
| 4 | 2023-02-21 | 9 |
| 5 | 2023-02-22 | 5 |

I know I could use `MAX` to get the max value of 9 but I also want to know the date when that value appears. How can I do that?

Comment: Will the values in the “B” column always be unique? If they will, you can achieve your objective by using the MAX, MATCH, and INDEX functions together.

Comment: Something like index(a:a,match(max(b:b),b:b,0)) but not tested

Comment: @Alper The values are not guaranteed to be unique. Now that I think of it I’m not sure what the best result would be if they aren’t.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is achieving desired result is using `LOOKUP` function.

"Algorithm" can be described as: "find maximum value in Values column and return corresponding row in Date column".

Assuming that data provided is in table starting from A1: maximum value (`MAX(C2:C6)`), range where to look for this value (`C2:C6`) and range where corresponding row should be returned (`B2:B6`):

`LOOKUP(MAX(C2:C6),C2:C6,B2:B6)`

Comment: I went with `XLOOKUP`, since that lets me control what happens if the max value isn't unique.